# Invalid CORS request in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cors

I am trying to enable certain IPs to access a particular method.

```java
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/updateDetail")
    .allowedOrigins("127.0.0.1", "10.96.33.45")
    .allowedMethods("GET", "POST");
}
```

But when I am trying to call the same method I am getting invalid CORS request. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Share the exact relevant error message / stack trace. Most probably the in-flight request itself fails since `OPTIONS` method is not in allowed list

Answer (score 8):

"Invalid CORS request" is returned by [org.springframework.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/cors/DefaultCorsProcessor.java) when

1. Spring is configured to use CORS and
2. browser sends "Origin" header with the request and it does not match with your server domain/port/scheme and
3. response does not have "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header and
4. the request is not a preflight request.

If you don't need CORS, call `cors().disable()` in your implementation of *WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure(HttpSecurity http)* (there might be other ways to do this, for example if you use  Spring Boot).

Or you could add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header to your reponses using e.g. *org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration* or *addCorsMappings* (like you did, but maybe you should add more methods or url or IP doesn't match?).

Answer (score 3):

This class is what are you looking for:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleCorsFilter implements Filter {

public SimpleCorsFilter() {
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "12000");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "*");

    if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}
}
```

This filter will resolve all your cors issues

Answer (score 1):

if you started your application at `localhost`, the browser formulates the origin as `null`, so application will not get the origin `localhost:8080` or `127.0.0.1`, it will get `null`

[image]

I think changing `127.0.0.1` with `null` will fix your problem

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/updateDetail")
    .allowedOrigins("null", "10.96.33.45")
    .allowedMethods("GET", "POST");
}
```

Comment: I also have this problem. Spring security uses redirection for SAML authentication within itself and the origin of that is null. So putting null in the allowedOrigins solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was debugging problem like this for few days. The actual problem was that I had typo in my service uri name /data vs. /daba etc. This cause SpringBoot to fail to retrieve CORS configuration (even when I had /** mapping) so CORS-preflight got status 403, which caused browser not to make the actual request at all - if browser would have fired the request, Spring would have returned "Resource not found" and then I would have noticed the typo much faster.